# Hovering over sibling stops hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, siblings

So I have two colour images that when hovered will turn the other to greyscale (there is a black and white copy of each image sitting directly behind) by changing the opacity to 0. This works fine.

I'm now trying to display a caption over the hovered image (when its hovered). What happens is that when I hover over the image, the caption appears just fine. If the mouse moves over the caption though, the caption just constantly disappears and reappears as I'm no longer hovering over the image itself. When the caption disappears I'm hovering on the image again so it reappears.

What I'd like to happen is that when I hover over this caption it behaves as though I'm still hovering the image. I would also accept displaying the caption over the image permanently as an alternative (might even be better in the long run to be honest).

I've looked into the event.stopPropagation() method but that seems to prevent effects moving up the DOM or something to that effect and this caption is a sibling.

Code is as follows

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftbox">
  <div id="upper" class="cap">
    <div class="gallery">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="link.html">
            <img src="images/img1_color.jpg" class="color" alt="a" id="img1>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="link.html">
            <img src="images/img1_dark.jpg" class="dark" alt="a">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="caption1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lower" class="cap">
    <div class="gallery">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="link2.html">
            <img src="images/img2_color.jpg" class="color" alt="b" id="img2>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="link2.html">
            <img src="images/img2_dark.jpg" class="dark" alt="b">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="caption2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gallery li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

img.dark {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

img.color {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#leftbox {
  float: left;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 5px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#leftbox #upper {
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#leftbox #lower {
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.gallery  #capimg1{
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: green;
  z-index:2;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 100px 5px 100px;
}

.gallery  #capimg2{
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: green;
  z-index:2;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 100px 5px 100px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
window["img1"] = "#img1";
window["img2"] = "#img2";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img.color').hover(function(ev) {
    if (this.id == "img1") {
      $(img2).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 600);
    }
    else if (this.id == "img2") {
      $(img1).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 600);
    }

    $('#cap'+this.id).stop().fadeIn(400).html(this.alt);
  },
  function reAnim() {
    $([img1, img2].join(",")).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    $('#cap'+this.id).css("display", "none");       }
  );
});
```

Side question: Is there a way to make the #capimg1 and #capimg2 divs the same width as the gallery div? If not I'll just create a div for each image and hardcode the width in.

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you put this on jsFiddle?  I started it for you but it needs some work http://jsfiddle.net/SSHf9/

Comment: The cause of the blinking effect is because when you hover the caption, the original hover effect of the image is gone so the caption disappears, but as soon as the caption disappears the image is once again hovered causing the caption to reappear. This loops endlessly. To fix it place the hoer on both elements (image and caption) or on the overall container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your javascript as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img.color').parents('div.cap').hover(function(ev) {
    if ($(this).find('img.color')[0].id == "img1") {
      $(img2).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 600);
    }
    else if (this.id == "img2") {
      $(img1).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 600);
    }

    $('#caption_'+$(this).find('img.color')[0].id).stop().fadeIn(400).html($(this).find('img.color')[0].alt);
  },
  function reAnim() {
    $([img1, img2].join(",")).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    $('#caption_'+$(this).find('img.color')[0].id).css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

And then change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="upper" class="cap">
  <div class="gallery">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="link.html">
          <img src="images/img1_color.jpg" class="color" alt="a" id="img1>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="link.html">
          <img src="images/img1_dark.jpg" class="dark" alt="a">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="caption_img1">
  </div>
</div>
```

**The important part of the above edit is changing the ID of the caption to something that we can easily associate with the img's ID**

What this does is place the hover effect not on the image itself, but the container.  Therefore, whenever your list item is hovered over, then the effect will be maintained, regardless what child is displayed or not displayed.

**EDIT**

Almost missed your side question.  If you want to make those the same size as your gallery div, you'll need to approach this one of two ways:

1. Set all elements below gallery to have a width of 100%

   ```
   .gallery ul, .gallery li, .gallery a, .gallery img {
     width: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. Set the width variable using your jQuery, like so:

   ```
   $('.gallery img').width($('.gallery').width());
   ```

**EDIT 2**

[Here's a working example of your first problem fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/5hR2V/)

Comment: Hey, I'm testing out your code and while I can get it to perform correctly with the changing image opacity etc, it doesn't show up the caption at all. Any tips ?

Comment: @Predz Ah, I see, your captions are outside the list.  My mistake.  I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Predz I updated the code accordingly, with a slight modification to your HTML to make the jQuery easier to work.

Comment: Thanks very much, works! Will the jquery width stuff still work correctly with the new code?

Comment: @Predz I don't see a reason why not.  Be sure to mark this as your answer if it did what you were hoping for.

Comment: Sorted it all out now. Thanks for the help.